# (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P18 (indeterminate_datatype), when it tries to query.

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have a query function, which gives `utc_date_from` and `utc_date_to` and takes sum of `total`.

Since I need to present local date, I added `time_period`, which is local date, into `select`.

```
time_period = to_string(date)
Payment
|> where([p], p.core_id == ^core_id and
              p.inserted_at >= datetime_add(^utc_date_from, 0, "day") and
              p.inserted_at <= datetime_add(^utc_date_to, 0, "day"))
|> select([p], %{amount: sum(p.total), time_period: ^time_period})
|> Repo.one()
```

However, if I add `time_period` into `select`, it triggers an error that `(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P18 (indeterminate_datatype): could not determine data type of parameter $1`.

In addition, this error only shows when I run my app in ubuntu. If I try with mac os, it does not show this error..

What is wrong with this function? how can I make it work in ubuntu?

Comment: Does this work: `time_period: type(^time_period, :string)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes Ecto is not able to determine the datatype so you could manually provide the datatype for `time_period`, see also https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#type/2:

```
time_period = to_string(date)
Payment
|> where([p], p.core_id == ^core_id and
          p.inserted_at >= datetime_add(^utc_date_from, 0, "day") and
          p.inserted_at <= datetime_add(^utc_date_to, 0, "day"))
|> select([p], %{amount: sum(p.total), time_period: type(^time_period, :string)})
|> Repo.one()
```